# Zuul is so slow when the count of end user is starting to increase

Tags: microservices, netflix-zuul, spring-cloud-netflix

There is a zuul gateway with this configuration:

```
spring:
  http:
    multipart:
      max-file-size: 20MB
      max-request-size: 20MB
  application:
    name: zuul-gateway
ribbon:
  ConnectTimeout: 20000000
  ReadTimeout: 20000000
  maxAutoRetries: 1
  MaxAutoRetriesNextServer: 2
  MaxTotalHttpConnections: 1600
  MaxConnectionsPerHost: 800
  eureka:
    enabled: true
zuul:
  hystrix:
    command:
      default:
        execution:
          isolation:
            strategy: SEMAPHORE
            semaphore:
              maxConcurrentRequests: 100000

        fallback:
          isolation:
            semaphore:
              maxConcurrentRequests: 100000
  semaphore:
    maxSemaphores: 100000
  eureka:
    default:
      semaphore:
        maxSemaphores: 100000
  host:
    connect-timeout-millis: 10000
    socket-timeout-millis: 60000

  routes:
    dominantUI:
      path: /micro1/View/m1/**
      serviceId: micro1
      stripPrefix: false
      sensitiveHeaders:


server:
  ssl:
    key-store: classpath:uu.jks
    key-store-password: wwww
    key-password: wwwww 
  port: 443
  compression:
    enabled: true
```

But when count of the end users forward near to 600, Zuul is so slow and It must be restarted and run again.

I have searched on Google and I am redirected to [Here](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/2247) and there were some tips such as use `okhttp` instead of `httpclient` and so on.

What is your some thing else idea and some else tuning configuration to improve the response time?

Comment: What do you mean here "But when count of the end users forward near to 600, Zuul is so slow and It must be restarted and run again" what do the users forward?  Stress test? Concurrently?

Comment: When the concurrent request are sent to zuul gateway, It is so slow